# Why is "example.it" safe and "www.example.it" unsafe?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have configured SSL/TLS on https://arieldemian.it but it seems that https://www.arieldemian.it is unsafe. Why is that? Do I need to register both of them? I am using https://www.startssl.com for the certificate. If you need other details please ask me in the comments and I will edit the question.

Comment: Who told you it was unsafe?

Comment: I just removed `www.arieldemian.it` as a redirect. I will work on it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

The *common name* you specified when you created your CSR must match *exactly* with the domain serving up the certificate.

As `EXAMPLE.COM` and `WWW.EXAMPLE.COM` are not the same you would need two certificates or a single (more expensive) wildcard certificate which would allow `*.EXAMPLE.COM`.

Comment: 0k. That explains everything. StartSSL allows a subdomain to be defined with the certificate so I should've defined the certificate for `arieldemian.it` and `www.arieldemian.it`.

Comment: DNS names should *not* be placed in the Common Name (CN). That practice is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/Browser Forums. Instead, DNS names should be put in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN). *If* a DNS name is place in the CN, then it must also be present in the SAN. There's no way to avoid placing a DNS name in the SAN.

Comment: Can you please link me some good documentation on the best practices for DNS's?

Comment: @jww I took a look on wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types but I can't find anything about CN records nor about SAN records.